# Trying to get sybase db to connect via isql command line.... Gui RazorSQL works

Tags: t-sql, jdbc, isql, jconnect

Im using RazorSQL and the settings to connect is

GUI RazorSQL Connections show as

```
 Driver Class  net.sourcefourge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

 Driver Location  /Java/drivers/jtds/jtds12.jar

 JDBC URL   jdbc:jtds:sybase://IP-address:4100/DATABASE
```

LINUX connections show

**/etc/freetds.conf**

```
[Serverconnection]

    host = 10.10.10.10
    port = 4100
    tds version = 8.0
    dump file = /var/log/freetds.log
```

**/etc/odbc.ini**

```
[Serverconnection]

     Driver          = /usr/local/freetds/lib/libtdsodbc.so
     Description     = Sybase JDBC Server
     Trace           = No
     Server          = 10.10.10.10
     Database        = SYB
     Port            = 4100
     TDS_Version     = 5.0
```

End goal is to connect to the sybase db Via command line so i can build them in bash scripts but i cant seem to connect to it via ISQL

not sure if theres a driver or jar needed or something really.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your odbc.ini file and use `Servername=Serverconnection` instead of `Server=10.10.10.10`. This points your odbc.ini file back to your freetds.conf file to get connection info, which is under `[Serverconnection]`. Whatever is in your freetds.conf need not be repeated in your odbc.ini file.